# send data from jsp to controller using model attribute

Tags: spring, jsp

```
<body>
<jsp:useBean id="loginBean" class="com.ss.sms.bean.LoginBean"></jsp:useBean>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Log in</div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    form:form id="loginForm"  method="post" action="login" modelAttribute="login">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="UserId" name="userId" type="text" autofocus="autofocus" value=${loginBean.userName}>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value=${loginBean.password}>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <div style="color: red">${error}</div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form:form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.col-->
</div><!-- /.row -->    

@RequestMapping(value="/login",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView login(Model md,@ModelAttribute("login")LoginBean loginBean) {
    System.out.println("hello done");
    System.out.println(loginBean.getUserName());
    ModelAndView model = null;
    if (loginBean != null && loginBean.getUserName() != null & loginBean.getPassword() != null) {
        if (loginBean.getUserName().equals("santosh") && loginBean.getPassword().equals("Santosh@123")) {
            model = new ModelAndView("hello");
            return model;
        } else {
            model = new ModelAndView("login");
            return model;
        }
    } else {
        model = new ModelAndView("login");
        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add explanation of what is wrong with your code?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly fromn your code you have problem seeing the page correctly.

In your ModelAndView you add just the view and not the model

So you need to add the object

Hence, the code can look something like that

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login",method = RequestMethod.POST) public ModelAndView login(Model md,@ModelAttribute("login")LoginBean loginBean) {
    System.out.println("hello done");
    System.out.println(loginBean.getUserName());
    ModelAndView model = null;
    if (loginBean != null && loginBean.getUserName() != null & loginBean.getPassword() != null) {
        if (loginBean.getUserName().equals("santosh") && loginBean.getPassword().equals("Santosh@123")) {
           //if the view hello expects an object add it here
            model = new ModelAndView("hello");
            return model;
        } else {
            model = new ModelAndView("login").addObject("login",loginBean);
            return model;
        }
    } else {
        model = new ModelAndView("login").addObject("login",loginBean);
        return model;
    } 
}
```